# propositional logic tableau by hand

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, book-recommendation

I was hoping recommend to me a good introduction to propositional logic tableaux that is designed to be done by hand on paper.

So far I've seen Graham's Priests approach (Introduction to non-Classical Logic) and Raymond Smullyan's (Beginners Guide to Logic), but they both seem to be not quite as clear as I would like for true beginners (e.g. 1st year college students).

For instance, the exact rules of "checking off" used formulas, and making clear the reason for why a branch occurs, don't seem to be clear enough to me in these accounts. At least, the informal way they are discussed would probably cause confusion among beginners.

So are there any good books or tutorials that you would recommend?

Comment: I am surprised those books aren't clear enough ... and so while I could recommend some other texts, I am not sure if they would really help. I am also confused that on the one hand you seem to be looking for the 'exact' rules (and think the accounts you have are too 'informal'), but at the same time you are wanting for ano explanation why branches occur or when to check off statements ... But exact rules are not going to explain to you why branches occur or why we check off statements; that's exactly what the informal explanations do!  So ... what is really your goal here?

Comment: Accounts of the propositional tableau construction are found in Smullyan's "First-Order Logic;" Fitting's "First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving;" Bell and Machover's "Course in Mathematical Logic;" and Ben-Ari's "Mathematical Logic for Computer Science."

Comment: Bram28: I am looking for exact book-keeping procedure for doing tableau by hand. Both Smullyan and Priest are informal about the book-keeping procedures, and focus more on setting it up for the meta-theory stuff that comes after. It seems, for instance, labelling each node with a reference to the formula responsible for it would make reading a completed tableau easier, similar to the way every line of a Lemmon-style proofs explicitly cites its justifications.